# Default Margin in material layout,

Tags: android, android-layout, gwt-material-design

I'm trying to make a **TextInputLayout** , in which i took a **TextInputEditText** , but even after setting the TextInputEditText margin to 0 , there is a default margin inside the layout, idk why but kind of confused.

[Screenshot for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls1YJ.png)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email Id"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TXTpassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/IMGlogo">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/TXTemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using this style `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` in `TextInputLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
android:insetBottom="0dp" 
android:insetTop="0dp"
android:insetRight="0dp"
android:insetLeft="0dp"
```